# Given a URL, how to encode a file's contents as base64 with Python / Django?

Tags: python, django, email, encoding

I am building a Django-based website, and am having trouble figuring out a decent way to email some larger PDFs and such to my users.

The files in question never touch our servers; they're handled on a CDN. So, my starting point is with the unique URLs for the files, not with the files themselves. It would be nice to find a solution that doesn't involve saving the files locally.

In order for me to be able to send the email in the way I want (with the PDF/DOCX/whatever attached to it), I need to be able to encode the attachment as a base-64 string.

I would prefer not to save the file to our server; I would also prefer not to read a response object in chunks and write it plainly to a file on our server, then encode that file.

That said, given a direct url to a file is there a way to stream the response and encode it in base64 as it comes in?

I have been reading about Django's `StreamingHttpResponse` and `FileWrapper` and feel like I am close, but I'm not able to put it together just yet.

Edit: the snippet below is working for now, but I'm worried about memory usage - how well would something like this scale?

```
import base64
req = requests.get('url')
encoded = base64.b64encode(req.content)
```

Comment: How big are these PDF files on average and how often will this run?

Comment: Usually around 10-15 megs. As for how often, usage will see spikes - long periods (a day or so) of nothing, then probably 30-50 requests like this an hour for a few hours.

Comment: Let's be conservative and say 60 requests per hour, and reading in each PDF has a 5x memory footprint (ie. 75 megs). So at its peak, that's one request per minute gobbling up 75 MB of memory. Assuming this is running on a reasonable system, I can't see this causing problems.

Comment: Thank you for explaining with an example - the lightbulb has finally come on on my end. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [beetea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387959/beetea) I am comfortable implementing the simple:

```
import base64
req = requests.get('url')
encoded = base64.b64encode(req.content)
```

As the solution to this issue.